# Android Studio bundle size vs gradle bundle size

Tags: android-studio, android-app-bundle

I have an Android project that I am bundling using new Android bundles 
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

The problem is that I have a remote server where a script runs and creates bundle with a following command:

```
./gradlew :app:bundleStage
```

The generated bundle is ~85 MB size and when uploaded to play store gets reduces to ~30MB in download size.

However if I create a bundle with Android studio

```
Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build Bundle(s)
```

generated bundle size is around 20MB and when uploaded get reduces to ~10MB in download size.

They both work, but I wonder why is that? In Android studio event log I see same gradle command executed, so why it's producing different size output?

I use same gradle version on my local machine and on remote host.

Comment: That seems odd indeed. Can you file a bug here please? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192709&template=842921 Also, if you could include the diff of the content of the bundles (they're just zipfiles), that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the culprit was C++ library we're using. For some reason on my machine debug symbols were stripped of automatically but not on the remote server. Once debug symbols were removed from the library itself the build size started to match.